# Non-blocking child process blocks file

Tags: perl

Consider this scenario:

We have three scripts:

script.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;


print "\nStarting a blocking process";
print "\nRedirect the output of the blocking process to execution.log";
my $cmd = "perl d:\\blocking_script.pl >d:\\execution.log";
my $exitCode = system ($cmd);
print "\nAfter the execution of the blocking process";

print "\nNow I try to rename the log";
rename "d:\\execution.log", "d:\\execution.err" or print "\nCouldn't rename because : $!";
```

blocking_script.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "\nFrom the blocking_process I run a non-blocking process";
my $cmd = "start perl d:\\non_blocking_script.pl";
my $exitCode = system ($cmd);
print "\nAfter I started the non-blocking process";
```

non_blocking_script.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "\nI am an independent non-blocking process";
sleep 5;
print "\nStill here";
sleep 2;
print "\nYou can't rename the log because you didn't wait for me";
sleep 3;
print "\n.";
sleep 1;
```

What will result from this?

```
Couldn't rename because : Permission denied
```

While another command promopt will be hanging ironically :

```
I am an independent non-blocking process
Still here
You can't rename the log because you didn't wait for me
.
```

In my situation from perl I run an external application in a blocking way, but that application was starting some non-blocking process which were holding my log.

How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: We can't tell what the question is, without assessing your answer on another post. Can't you post the pertinent information in your question here so we can answer it?

Comment: @samiles Updated

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [documentation for `start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx) (which you should also be able to read by using `start /?` on the command line. I do not have access to a Windows system right now, so I can't verify.

> `/b`
>
> Starts an application without opening a new Command Prompt window. <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> handling is ignored unless the application enables <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> processing. Use <kbd>CTRL+BREAK</kbd> to interrupt the application.

`blocking_script.pl` is waiting for the cmd window which `start` opened to run `non_blocking_script.pl`.

In the short run, using `start /b` might help.

Or, you could try

```
my @cmd = start => qw(perl d:\\non_blocking_script.pl);
my $exitCode = system @cmd;
```

However, you should [change your design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, both solutions are not working, the rename still fails with `Permission denied`. On the second solution, another "weird" thing happens, a command prompt is opened.